# inserting data in codeigniter with simplest example and explain MVC in short

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my model.But dont know how to insert data in database.Actually i am new to codeigniter please tell me some simple example of data insertion, maybe of form data insertion.

```
<?php        
class News_model extends CI_Model {            
        public function __construct(){         
                $this->load->database();                
        }                                            
        public function get_news($slug = FALSE){                
        if ($slug === FALSE){                        
                $query = $this->db->get('news');                 
                return $query->result_array();                         
        }                                             
        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug));                   
        return $query->row_array();                
}                  
public function view($slug = NULL){    
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);    
        if (empty($data['news_item'])){    
                show_404();    
        }    

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];    
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);    
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);`enter code here`    
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');    
}
}
```

Comment: your mixing controller and model try to read manual http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: can u please tell me any simple example of form with two field@JYoThI

Comment: Hi please refer this link http://www.phptutorials.club/crud-using-codeigniter-and-mysql/

Comment: first of all study about mvc

Comment: its look nice tutorial https://www.formget.com/form-login-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example would be,

```
$data['title']    = $_POST['title'];
$data['content']  = $_POST['content'];
$data['date']     = time();
$this->db->insert('news', $data);
```

Note: You collect data to `$data` variable and `insert` them to `news` table.

Please read more about [CodeIgniter models](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

PS: I see you have some miss understanding on MVC by looking at your code. Read more on that. Basically Model is used to get, insert and update data into a table. (a table == model). The best place to make a call to your view is from the controller. We call the model from the Controller -> Get values from model -> Controller receives the data -> Controller pass them to specific view. Controller handles the logic. Model does not know any logic OR to what view he should pass the data.

There are good tutorials about CodeIgniter in youtube as well. They also explains the MVC.

Good Luck